# Exchanging OAuth/OIDC Access Token

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, token-exchange

I have this use case and I'm wondering how to effectively use [token-exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8693) protocol. My use case is this:

1. App 1 authenticates with OAuth server (OIDC) and obtains ID token and Access Token. And it can use access token to call APIs (eg: userInfo and other APIs) on OAuth server. AccessToken has **client_id** as App1 and **aud** as OAuthServer.
2. I need to solve this use case : ***App 1 has to pass a "*token*" to App 2. App 2 validates the "*token*" does some operation; and App 2 also has to call APIs on OAuth server.***

After reading token-exchange flows, I was thinking of the following:

a) App1 uses its AccessToken to call token-exchange to get "**token2**" for App2. "**token2**" contains **client_id** as **App1** and **aud** as **App2**

b) App1 passes the **token2** to App2. App2 validates **aud** claim, and does some operation.

c) App2 passes "**token2**" to call token-exchange to get "**token3**" for App2. "**token3**" contains **client_id** as **App2** and **aud** as **OAuthServer**

d) App2 can use **token3** to call OAuthServer.

Let me know if there is a better to way to do this.

Comment: If you want to do delegation/impersonation then this is the right way. If the subsequent calls do not need delegation/impersonation of the original token owner then they can use independent tokens acquired earlier via client_credential grant type.